# Send Post Request from other domain to GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post

I have write an simple python application on GAE.

```
class Upload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write('HelloWorld')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(['/upload', Upload)],
                              debug=True)
```

And it can receive post request.

But there is something with it.

---

**I write one test page.**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/upload" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="content"/>
      <input type="submit"  value="submit local"/>     
    </form>
    <form action="http://wp7-gps-tracker.appspot.com/upload" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="content"/>
      <input type="submit"  value="submit server"/>     
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

The Result

**Run in localhost:**

Test with IE:Success!

Test with Chrome:Success!

**Upload to GAE:**

Test with IE:faild!

Test with Chrome:Success!

what's wrong with my application?

**I find the problem!**

**The GAE was forbidden in china!**

**And my Chrome is using proxy so it can works!**

**In your face, Chinese government！**

Comment: Can you show any more details about what Python code is running on the server side?

Comment: +jgeewax I have changed my question.

Comment: Any chance that the handler requires a logged-in user, and Chrome happens to be logged in on both your local dev_appserver and on to your app on appspot.com? (And IE isn't)?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith  I try to Logout in Chrome and Login in IE. And I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change action relative your environment ... GAE have different url for version of application.

```
action="/upload"
```

Comment: they are not on the same service.

Comment: with my test page? What's your version of IE？ I am IE7 under Windows7 X64

Comment: :-)  I found your log in my GAE!   187.115.103.227 - - [09/Jun/2012:10:56:29 -0700] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 115 - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"

Comment: Thanks a lot~ I have found the problem.

Comment: @Dozer What the solution please! :D Your question is need response.

Answer (score 0):

Try only using 1 form in your test page, maybe IE is having problem distinguishing which form to submit